# Transistor compatibility

Tags: transistors, power

I can't find this part anywhere. What other power transistors would suit? It's silicon body. Would 2SC3904 be good?

[image: C3940AQ Transistor Image]

*([Original](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFwBo.jpg))*

Answer (score 2):

The [2SC3940AQ](https://alltransistors.com/adv/pdfview.php?doc=2sc3940_e.pdf&dire=_panasonic) is a beefy 60V 1A transistor with a larger case than TO-92 for higher dissipation capability. Beta bin 85-170.

Except for the voltage rating, an [SS8050B](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/149/SS8050-117753.pdf) (lowest beta bin) with an added heatsink (and different pinout usually) might do. The 25V capacitor suggests the 25V 8050 may be adequate.

The part number and photo suggest an audio amplifier application- using a part with a much higher beta than the original may result in the bias being too far off.